# CountIF by Color AND by Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I will start by saying while I have some basic coding knowledge, I know nothing about VBA and it looks so different from other languages I've seen and used that it might as well be alien to me.

I have a table of values in Excel that represent the impact of a test I've run (ranging from 1-12).

In order for me to visually determine whether the test passed or not, I've highlighted the cells GREEN or RED. I had hoped that I could do some sort of Boolean AND to combine counting based on the value of the cells and it's background color. While I've found a few different functions already written for just counting by background color, I could not figure out how to modify them to also include an additional variable for the cell value.

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
Function CountCellsByFontColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long

    Application.Volatile
    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Font.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Font.Color Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    CountCellsByFontColor = cntRes
End Function
```

How do I modify the above to include an additional variable to match the value of the cell?

Comment: Something like `If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Font.Color and cellCurrent.value = ??? Then` where `???` is whatever value or string you want

Comment: sigh. Life would be so much easier if people stopped manually color coding Excel cells. You can use the logic that goes on in your head to create conditional formatting. You can use the same logic to use formulas to summarise the data, then you don't need VBA at all. So, what inner rules do you follow to determine if a test has passed? That can be expressed as a formula.

Comment: Conditional Formatting